# Results of an iterative prefix sum

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix, sum

An array of size `s + 1` is initialized such that `a[i] = i` for `0 <= i < s` , `a[s] = 0`. Then I iteratively use dynamic programming to sum the values of the array, going from **largest to smallest**, doing it `t` times. Results get large very quickly so I reduce them mod some `modulus`.

If `s = 10`, the arrays look like this:

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`

`[0, 45, 44, 42, 39, 35, 30, 24, 17, 9, 0]`

`[0, 45, 89, 131, 170, 205, 235, 259, 276, 285, 0]`

And so on.

After `t` iterations I am interested in the extreme non-zero values of the array. My algorithm does this explicitly, resulting in time complexity of `O(s*t)`. Is there any algorithm that can produce either (or both) of these values in a better time complexity? Specifically I was thinking about whether matrix exponentiation is possible, reducing time complexity to `O(s*log(t))`, but really any approach is welcome as well as optimizations.

My code:

```
public class ArraySummation{

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        int s = 10;
        long t = 10;
        
        long modulus = 1000000;
        
        long [] a = new long [s + 1];
        for (int i = 1 ; i < s ; i++)
            a[i] = i;

        for (int i = 2 ; i <= t ; i++)
        {
            if ((i & 1) == 1)
                for (int j = 1 ; j < a.length - 1 ; j++)
                {
                    a[j] += a[j - 1];
                    if (a[j] >= modulus)
                        a[j] -= modulus;
                }

            else
                for (int j = a.length - 2 ; j >= 1 ; j--)
                {
                    a[j] += a[j + 1];
                    if (a[j] >= modulus)
                        a[j] -= modulus;
                }
        }

        System.out.println(a[1]);
        System.out.println(a[s - 1]);
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem's description is inconsistent with the examples, please review it. E.g. If initialized with a[i]=i the initial array should be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. Also in the second row you sum left to right, and in the third right to left.

Comment: @Rocco because I sum the values largest to lowest. Hence switching from summing left-right to right-left. Otherwise it wouldn't necessarily be largest to lowest.

Comment: Ok, so you only need the zeroes at the two ends to avoid and index of bounds, right?

Comment: @Rocco Yes, for bounds, and also to make sure the sum is done properly. Because each "starting" value is + 0 from the previous one. They are not needed per-se for the problem, they are only needed for the algorithm itself. I assume they are somewhat redundant and can be spared in a way, but they don't bother me so I leave them there.

Comment: @MCFromScratch `a[i] = i` and resultant array `[0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` do not match even we ignore the leading and trailing zero.

Comment: @MCFromScratch Just a guess but the initial array will always be of the form `[1 2 3 4....n]` if I am not wrong? This is a sequence and after summing it for the first time, another sequence will be there. If someone comes up with a formula for doing it `t` times, it will be `O(1)`. Just an observation though.

Comment: @AKSingh You are correct. True, a closed form formula may exist.. But I cannot figure it out. For the first row it's the the `n`th triangular number. In general, for `s = 10`, the values are in https://oeis.org/search?q=45%2C285%2C1695&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For s=10 it can be found in OEIS https://oeis.org/A030113 as a linear recurrence.

There is also a formula in matrix form  for all s

```
(PARI) k=9; M(k)=matrix(k, k, i, j, if(1-sign(i+j-k), 0, 1)); v(k)=vector(k, i, 1); a(n)=vecmax(v(k)*M(k)^n)
```

Sample for the matrix construction

[Matrix construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BCJU.png)

**Explanation**
The Matrix M operates by multiplication to Matrix T as follows to the result matrix R (short: M . T = R)

- First column of R is the last column of T
- Second column of R is the sum of the last and second last column of T
- ...
- Last column of R is the sum of all columns of T

Thus the adding procedure of the question is done by matrix multiplication, but with initialization `a[i] = 1`. After first round with M^2 the last column contains the initialization of the question `a[i] = i`

[M^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylhgo.png)

Depending on the parameters s, t it could be better to use the matrix exponentiation like M^8 = M^4 . M^4 = M_4 . M_4 , M^4 = M^2 . M^2 = M_2 . M_2, where M_2 and M_4 can be reused. So instead of 8 matrix mulitiplications with only 3 multiplication we can get the result.

The complexity is O(s^2 * log(t))

Comment: I have noticed this OEIS entry. Didn't really understand this procedure, might as well be black magic!

Comment: I added a picture how the matrix is constructed

Comment: It should be a lot faster with matrix exponentiation, that's why I think that's the way if it's possible. Do you understand exactly why this works? and why this is the matrix?

Comment: I described the matrix. Hopefully this will help you.